# GetWindowlong to check button style

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I would like to use raw winapi32 to check button style whether it is a checkbox button or a pushbutton.

```
bool isPushBtn(HWND hBtn, DWORD dwStyle)
{
   return (0!=dwStyle | GetWindowLong(hBtn,GWL_STYLE));
}
```

But this always returns false. Do you know a way to check this ? Thank you.

Comment: what are you passing as `dwStyle`?

Comment: Thanks , I use BS_PUSHBUTTON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to understand how button styles work we need to look at the values used by the style constants:

```
#define BS_PUSHBUTTON       0x00000000L
#define BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON    0x00000001L
#define BS_CHECKBOX         0x00000002L
#define BS_AUTOCHECKBOX     0x00000003L
#define BS_RADIOBUTTON      0x00000004L
#define BS_3STATE           0x00000005L
#define BS_AUTO3STATE       0x00000006L
#define BS_GROUPBOX         0x00000007L
#define BS_USERBUTTON       0x00000008L
#define BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON  0x00000009L
#define BS_PUSHBOX          0x0000000AL
#define BS_OWNERDRAW        0x0000000BL
#define BS_TYPEMASK         0x0000000FL
#define BS_LEFTTEXT         0x00000020L

#define BS_TEXT             0x00000000L
#define BS_ICON             0x00000040L
#define BS_BITMAP           0x00000080L
#define BS_LEFT             0x00000100L
#define BS_RIGHT            0x00000200L
#define BS_CENTER           0x00000300L
#define BS_TOP              0x00000400L
#define BS_BOTTOM           0x00000800L
#define BS_VCENTER          0x00000C00L
#define BS_PUSHLIKE         0x00001000L
#define BS_MULTILINE        0x00002000L
#define BS_NOTIFY           0x00004000L
#define BS_FLAT             0x00008000L
#define BS_RIGHTBUTTON      BS_LEFTTEXT
```

The other essential reference is the [Button Styles topic at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951%28VS.85%29.aspx). However, what that document does not explain is that the `BS_PUSHBUTTON` to `BS_OWNERDRAW` flags, the *type* flags, are mutually exclusive. The other flags can be used in combination with one of the type flags. This can be inferred from the bit patterns of the values.

The documentation for `BS_TYPEMASK` states:

> Windows 2000: A composite style bit that results from using the OR operator on BS_* style bits. It can be used to mask out valid BS_* bits from a given bitmask. Note that this is out of date and does not correctly include all valid styles. Thus, you should not use this style.

However I think this is misleading and endorse what ybungalobill said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293212/getwindowlong-to-check-button-style/7293254#7293254). No harm can come of following that advice.

In other words you should mask the style with `BS_TYPEMASK` and then test for a particular button type.

```
bool isButtonType(HWND hBtn, DWORD dwType)
{
     assert(dwType<=BS_TYPEMASK);
     return (GetWindowLong(hBtn, GWL_STYLE) & BS_TYPEMASK) == dwType;
}
```

Comment: congratulations, from the distributivity of & and |, your code is just an obfuscated way to write `(GetWindowLong(hBtn, GWL_STYLE) & 0xF) != 0`,

Comment: @ybungalobill I don't understand what you mean, and as I say, my expertise is not C++

Comment: It's not C++, it's math. `!((x & y1) != 0) && !((x & y2) != 0)` iff `(x & y1) == 0 && (x & y2) == 0` iff `(x & (y1 | y2)) == 0`. Apply the above for `yn` equal to each of BS_* and you get that your check is equivalent to `(style & (BS_3STATE | BS_AUTO3STATE | BS_GROUPBOX | ... )) == 0`. But the bitwise-or of all these constants equals 0xf, so what you check is in fact `(style & 0xf) == 0` (yes, sorry, I meant equality in my previous comment).

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
return (GetWindowLong(hBtn,GWL_STYLE) & BS_TYPEMASK) == dwStyle;
```

Comment: Documentation for `BS_TYPEMASK` states: "Note that this is out of date and does not correctly include all valid styles. Thus, you should not use this style."

Comment: @David: Yes it does. So what? This is the best general thing you can do, and it works for anything below Vista.

Comment: @David: well, good to know, fortunately I didn't ever rely on this; unfortunately in many other cases it works like that, so it's easy to get it wrong. `:S`

Comment: @David: the space of the values of GWL_STYLE is a direct sum of space of the types of the button (check box, radio, etc...) and some other orthogonal spaces (text alignment, flatness, notifications, etc...). Your answer says 'test for the presence of ...'. How? The test is done by projecting on the subspace of the types and comparing that coordinate. So yes, microsoft extended this subspace and didn't provide us a mask for that, so the only correct way is to hard code that mask by expecting the documented values of the types.

Comment: @David: I assume that the OP uses the kind of button it wants to test, i.e. dwStyle is already the coordinate in the button-type subspace.

Comment: @David: no I can't. `BS_FLAT != 0` but it's still a `BS_PUSHBUTTON`.

Comment: @David: BS_PUSHBUTTON if you want to check for BS_PUSHBUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON to check for BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, BS_GROUPBOX to check for BS_GROUPBOX, etc...

Comment: Finally I understand what you mean about the space of types and then the other orthogonal spaces. Upvoted and my answer deleted. Sorry, I was being unusually dim, even for me.

Comment: @Matteo Turns out I was wrong. Although some flags are used in combination, the types are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
return (dwStyle == (GetWindowLongPtr(hBtn, GWL_STYLE) & dwStyle));
```

Comment: Thanks, I pass in dwStyle BS_PUSHBUTTON whose value is 0 therefore when GetWindowLongPtr fails (return 0),the above statement becomes true, which actually doesn't help me to check whether the given button is push or checkbox type.